# AWS static site endpoint not loading correctly

Tags: amazon-s3, dns, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, hsts

I followed quite a complicated AWS guide on setting a static hosting for my website, and it’s currently not loading, not sure why. What I have done:

1. Created S3 bucket for the contents of the site `estimate.dev`
2. Uploaded index.html to the root of the S3 bucket
3. Unblocked all access to public in the "Prermissions -> Block Public Access" tab
4. Added Bucket policy for public access:

```xml
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Id": "PolicyForPublicWebsiteContent",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "s3:GetObject",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::estimate.dev/*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

5. Added “Static website hosting” feature pointing to the domain `estimate.dev` and index file `index.html`
6. Added Route 53 zone for `estimate.dev` with auto-generated SOA and NS records. Set TTL of 60 seconds for each. 
   [image: Imag]
7. Added A record pointing to my S3 bucket (selected in combobox)
   [image]
8. Changed nameservers in my registrar's control panel to point to AWS nameservers listed in SOA record
   [image]
9. A day passed

Now the troubleshooting part:

1. On my PC `estimate.dev` resolves to AWS IP (it was resolving Registrar IP 2 days ago)
2. These urls perfectly return the contents of my website (just one page, index.html):
   http://estimate.dev.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
   https://s3.amazonaws.com/estimate.dev/index.html
3. These urls [http://estimate.dev] & [https://estimate.dev] return `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` in Chrome after loading for some time

I tried to delete A record and add a CNAME but it does not allow me to select my S3 bucket there. So I reverted back to A record.

What do I miss here?

Comment: You just need alias record and I think you already have it and it's working, the website is working on http because static website doesn't support https. curl -I http://estimate.dev
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: KP4yTlvx3xGH10sMpUs0OgEDvsHFg7ID0yCmtzUDCDuiPt40DtwVqWKn7ueMbZfFb17WSOqmQKs=
x-amz-request-id: DBE5A34D4D8ADF35
Date: Tue, 25 Jun 2019 13:43:28 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 24 Jun 2019 16:41:46 GMT
ETag: "7625d61cf4be9dbb1fac1275d2a0ffa3"
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1292
Server: AmazonS3

Comment: the problem isn't with Route53 and S3, many browsers uses HSTS and try for https which S3 website endpoint doesn't support, you need cloudfront for that. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/

Comment: I've just tried the "curl estimate.dev" on my cmd, and it works giving me the index.html contents, but neither https://estimate.dev not http://estimate.dev work in my browser

Comment: Yes, because browser is trying for https ()because of hsts policy) and S3 website endpoint doesn't support https and it gets timedout, try safari, it will load it on http.

Comment: Oh why does the tutorial even suggests to go this way that will not work in most modern browsers (facepalm)

Comment: yes, it worked on my phone in Safari

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/ follow above link if you want it to work on https.

Comment: Yes, I will do it. Feel free to create an answer for me to accept it

Comment: @v.karbovnichy the problem is not simply "modern browser" behavior.  This normally would have worked.  The reason this isn't working is because at some point in the past, your domain was configured for strict transport security, so it is on the preload list as a domain that is unwilling to work without HTTP. https://hstspreload.org/?domain=estimate.dev

Comment: I saw on some initial registrar page that this full TLD is supposed to work on SSL only, but I did not pay enough attention to this restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is correct except S3 website endpoint (not the REST API) doesn't support HTTPS and many modern browsers tries for https because of HSTS policy and you'll see connection timeout.

To make it work on HTTPS, you can use CloudFront and set up using below link:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/